# JQuery Tools Scrollable: On Click, stop scrolling?

Tags: jquery, scroll, scrollable

I am using the scrollable plugin, excellent stuff and works the way I want.

The only thing I want to change is the following:

I have a list of linked images that scroll. When I click on an image, the scroller still scrolls and looks a bit odd. How do I stop it when a user clicks on a link?

```
$("#scroller").scrollable().circular().autoscroll({autoplay: true, steps: 1});
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

**EDIT**

Tried this code as suggested by Patrick, doesn't seem to work.

```
$("#scroller").scrollable().circular().autoscroll({autoplay: true, steps: 1});

$('#scroller .box').click(function()
{
      $("#scroller").stop();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it;

```
$("#scroller").scrollable({clickable: false}).circular().autoscroll({autoplay: true, steps: 1});
```

Comment: Excellent, now accept this answer for the next person who comes looking :)

Comment: I can't yet Nick, I have to wait 2 days.